# Prove $\mathscr{F}[{x^nf(x)}] = (j)^n\times \mathscr{F}^n[f(x)]$

Tags: fourier-analysis

How to prove this property of Fourier Transform:

$$\mathscr{F}[{x^nf(x)}] = (j)^n\times \mathscr{F}^n[f(x)]$$ 
 Fourier Transform's definition is:
$$\mathscr{F}[f(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{-jwx}f(x)d(x)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I_{1} = \int x \, e^{-i\omega x} \, f(x) \, dx.
\end{align}
This can be seen as
\begin{align}
I_{1} = i \frac{d}{d\omega} \int e^{-i \omega x} f(x) \, dx.
\end{align}
Extending this to
\begin{align}
I_{n} = \int x^{n} \, e^{-i \omega x} f(x) \, dx
\end{align}
leads to
\begin{align}
I_{n} = i^{n} \frac{d^{n}}{d\omega^{n}} \int e^{-i \omega x} f(x) \, dx.
\end{align}
Now it is seen that
\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}[{x^{n} \, f(x)}] = i^{n} \frac{d^{n}}{d\omega^{n}} \mathscr{F}[{f(x)}]
\end{align}
as required.